# Test explorer for visual studio mac

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I could not able to associate unit tests with test cases from Visual Studio Mac version as test explorer is not visible for Mac version, do we have any alternative way to do this

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac has a Unit Tests window which shows unit tests with test cases. Is that not working for you? If not then can you explain what features you are missing?

Comment: If we look in windows you can find the option 'Associate Test Case', in Mac the option is missing

Comment: There is no support for associating Azure DevOps test cases with code in Visual studio for Mac.